# Slider Set Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've done to make this work. Something like this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ewYc3/16/). But I want to make deep further again. I want to make this expand automatically when the page loads. However, I tried so far and couldn't make this work. Here is my codings.

HTML

```
<div id="adsBox">
        <a id="ads" class="bg90" href="#"></a>
        <div> <a id="showLink" class="showAds">SHOW</a> </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
 #adsBox{
    text-align:right;
    width:400px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:#E0E0E0;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 6px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
}
#ads{

    display: block;
}

.bg90
{
    background: url(http://i60.tinypic.com/16gkd5c.jpg) 400px 90px;
    height: 90px;
}
.bg200
{
    background: url(http://i60.tinypic.com/b9hx60.gif) 400px 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
#adsBox a {
    color:#000;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    cursor: pointer;

}

#adsBox a:hover {
    color:#4682b4;
}

#ads img {
    width:100%;
}

#showLink {
    text-decoration:none;
}

.hideLink {
    display:none;
}   

.expandImage {
    display:none;
}
```

and jQuery

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $("#ads").slideToggle(1000);
    }, 300);

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.showAds').click(function () {
        if ($(this).text() == 'HIDE') {
            $(this).text('SHOW');
            $('#ads').animate({height:"90px"}, 400, function() { $('#ads').toggleClass('bg200'); });
        } else {
            $(this).text('HIDE');
            $('#ads').animate({height:"200px"}, 400);
            $('#ads').toggleClass('bg200');
        }

    });
});
```

The problem is, when the page loads, the image slide up. What I want is the image (height 90px) will expand into (height 200px) automatically. Any ideas?

Comment: like this? http://jsfiddle.net/ewYc3/20/

Comment: Yes something like that, can you help me to make it slide down automatically after 3 seconds? And also then button will change into HIDE as well. HIDE is to make it back as normal, not to hide the images.. @Chad

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ewYc3/21/

Comment: Hey thank you very much, can you put the answer there? I would like to mark this up. @Chad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
http://jsfiddle.net/ewYc3/26/ (method after 3 seconds)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(function() {
    goToggle();
}, 3000);
    $('.showAds').click(function () {
        goToggle();
    });
});
function goToggle(){
   if ($('.showAds').text() == 'HIDE') {
    $('.showAds').text('SHOW');
    $('#ads').animate({height:"90px"}, 400, function() { 
        $('#ads').toggleClass('bg200'); });
    } else {
        $('.showAds').text('HIDE');
        $('#ads').animate({height:"200px"}, 400);
        $('#ads').toggleClass('bg200');
    }
}
```